# NgRx: Opening MatDialog from effect causes an immutability error

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx, immutability, ngrx-effects

In an ngrx effect I've tried to open a MatDialog for showing an error message, but it causes an error.

**Cannot add property 10, object is not extensible**

If I disable the `strictActionImmutability` check, everything works fine.
Someone has an idea how to solve this issue?

My effects is

```
public saveTemplateDetailError$ = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(saveTemplateDetailValidationError),
        exhaustMap( action => {
            let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent);
            return dialogRef.afterClosed();
        })
    ), {dispatch: false});
```

Version I use

- Angular: 11.0.2
- Material: 11.0.1
- NgRx: 11.0.1

Comment: Please share your respective code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to `entryComponents` on your `@NgModule`

Comment: Already have my modal component into `entryComponents` array.